# OpenGL UVs behave weird?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to implement a system for creating GUIs with OpenGL. For some applications like bitmap-fonts it would be nice to have an offset for the textures that should be rendered on an object.

So my offset in the vertex shader looks like this:

```
UV = vec2(uv.x, 1.0f - uv.y) + vec2(texOffset.x, texOffset.y);
```

I tested my offset using a rectangle with an offset that I continuously make larger.

Adding this offset on the x-axis looks like this:
https://youtu.be/z7bKgb7zcPc which is fine.

Using my offset on the y-axis looks like this:
https://youtu.be/2S_duM5JK_w this is also fine.

But now applying the offset on the x- and y-axis looks like this:
https://youtu.be/t_aJbQwbagw which is not fine.

Shouldn't it move like this: https://youtu.be/0GzPRpIaabE?

Why does my result differ from what I expect?

Comment: I don't see the problem. Increasing the x offset moves the texture to the left. Increasing the y offset moves the texture up. Increasing the x and y offset moves the texture up and to the left. Where's the problem?

Comment: The y-axis moves in both videos along the up arrow. Where is the flipping?

Comment: @Kerndog73 I added a video of what I think it should look like...

Comment: @BDL in the third video it moves down...

Comment: This is the third video https://youtu.be/t_aJbQwbagw and the texture moves up and to the left. You're telling me it moves down?

Comment: Could you describe your issue more clearly?

Comment: Add before flip then

Comment: @SneakyTurtle what do you mean? What should I describe?

Comment: @Kerndog73 I found the problem, my positive x direction was the problem... 
I wanted it to move to the right when x gets positive but it went to the left, so that's the problem. It would be nice if the question could be reopened so that I can answer the question properly.

Comment: @user11914177 start by editing your question to ask a proper one. Currently you ask why y is flipped between video 2 and 3, but it didn't change direction.

Comment: @BDL I think the question is now ready for my answer...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I found the problem. There isn't a bug in OpenGL, the problem is that my offset is wrong for the x axis.

I expected for a positive x offset, that the texture moves right. But I forgot to implement the flip that was required for that. **But I didn't remember that**, so from my expectation, the output was wrong, but it was just me...